# eheap allocated in erlang

Tags: memory, erlang

I use recon_alloc:memory(allocated_types) and get info like below.

```
34> recon_alloc:memory(allocated_types).
[{binary_alloc,1546650440},
 {driver_alloc,21504840},
 {eheap_alloc,28704768840},
 {ets_alloc,526938952},
 {fix_alloc,145359688},
 {ll_alloc,403701800},
 {sl_alloc,688968},
 {std_alloc,67633992},
 {temp_alloc,21504840}]
```

The eheap_alloc is using 28G. But sum up with heap_size of all process

```
>lists:sum([begin {_, X}=process_info(P, heap_size), X end || P <- processes()]).
683197586
```

Only 683M !Any idea where is the 28G ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not comparing the right values. From [erlang:process_info](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-1)

> {heap_size, Size}
>   Size is the size in **words** of youngest heap generation of the 
>   process. This generation currently include the stack of the process.
>   This information is highly implementation dependent, and may change if
>   the  implementation change.

recon_alloc:memory(allocated_types) is in **bytes** by default. You can change it using set_unit. It is not the memory that is currently used but it is the memory reserved by the VM grouped into different allocators. You can use recon_alloc:memory(used) instead. More details in [allocator() - Recon Library](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fferd.github.io%2Frecon%2Frecon_alloc.html&ei=K6IBVag0sI-xBMPOgPgD&usg=AFQjCNG-2l5Hgo-UGCwpQC7BB-vvqu_RJg&sig2=G07-AzMCHgASdf5Wc0ieUA)

Comment: eheap also includes the old heap, heap_size only includes young heap.

Answer (score 0):

Searching through the Erlang source code for the eheap_alloc keyword I didn't come up with much. The most relevant piece of code was this XML code from erts_alloc.xml (https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/172e812c491680fbb175f56f7604d4098cdc9de4/erts/doc/src/erts_alloc.xml#L46):

```
<tag><c>eheap_alloc</c></tag>
<item>Allocator used for Erlang heap data, such as Erlang process heaps.</item>
```

This says that process heaps are stored in `eheap_alloc` but it doesn't say what else is stored in `eheap_alloc`. **The `eheap_alloc` stores everything your application needs to run along with some extra memory** along with some additional space, so the VM doesn't have to request more memory from the OS every time something needs to be added. **There are things the VM must keep in memory that aren't associated with a specific process.** For example, large binaries, even though they may used within a process, are not stored inside that processes heap. They are stored in a shared process binary heap called `binary_alloc`. The binary heap, along with the process heaps and some extra memory, are what make up `eheap_alloc`.

In your case it looks like you have a lot of memory in your `binary_alloc`. `binary_alloc` is probably using a significant portion of your `eheap_alloc`.

For more details on binary handling checkout these pages:

- http://blog.bugsense.com/post/74179424069/erlang-binary-garbage-collection-a-love-hate
- http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#id65224